# Create array from another array and a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in this form

```
([0] => 'string1' [1] => 'string2' [2] => 'string3' )
```

and a variable $lenght that I got from strlen(). Now I need to create an array in this form

```
('string1' => $lenght  'string2' => $lenght 'string3' => $lenght )
```

Any idea on how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `foreach()`. Example:

```
$arr = array('string1','string2','string3');
$length = "Your Val";
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $newArr[$val] = $length;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
$a = array('Hello', 'World', 'PHP');
$a = array_flip($a);
array_walk($a, function(&$val, $key) {
    $val = strlen($key); 
});
var_dump($a);
```

Here is the result of this code: http://3v4l.org/HfUKN

You may also replace the array_walk call with a `for` loop using a reference for the value.